# how to make my json valid

Tags: javascript, json

I've got an array:

```
var myArray = [
    {question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
     choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
     correctAnswer:0}, 
    {question: "What is the capital of UK?", 
     choices: ["Paris", "Washington", "London", "Liverpool"], 
     correctAnswer:2}];
```

After I stringified it. It looked like this:

```
JSON.stringify(myArray)
"[
     {
      "question":"Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
      "choices":[
                  "David Cameron","Gordon Brown",
                  "Winston Churchill",
                  "Tony Blair"
                ],
      "correctAnswer":0
     },
     {
       "question":"What is the capital of UK?",
       "choices":[
                   "Paris",
                   "Washington",
                   "London",
                   "Liverpool"
                 ],
       "correctAnswer":2
     }
]"
```

Which is not valid JSON. How to make it valid?

Comment: JSON.stringify **always** produces valid JSON - or throws trying

Comment: The JSON you show looks OK except that it has quotes `"` around it. Where do they come from?

Comment: probably from the console

Comment: If you're copying/pasting this into some online JSON validator and its failing, make sure you omit those outermost quotes!  The first and last character should be [ and ], respectively - not the double quotes.

Comment: " from the console, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the `"` characters from the two far ends.

Note, however, that they are not part of the output of `JSON.stringify`, they are added *to the display* by your developer console to indicate that the output is a string. This means you only need to remove them if you are copy/pasting the output from your console.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it is valid without " I shoud have figured it out myself. Sorry to bother :)